# can I train a multi-label model with single-labeled data?

Tags: text, model

I've been researching the following scenerio- I have text documents that are already labeled with single labels- ex: medical, financial, health etc, and I want to train a model that will be able to take a document that may contain a mixture of topics and give me labels of say 50% medical and 50% financial. Can I train a model such as a naive bayes wrapped in a multi_output_classifier on only the single-labeled documents? Will this enable me to predict multiple labels for a document that is a mix of topics?

Basically, I'd like to cut down the time it would take to label my documents for training by only training with the ones that are clear-cut single-label documents, and then use this model to predict on the documents I have that are a mix of topics, and on other single-topic documents as well.